# How to get count of column values for each unique pair of columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data that is given below

```
data = [(datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 6, 50, 14, 955551), 'blr', 'del', 'medium'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 7, 6, 0, 242578), 'lon', 'del', 'medium'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 7, 16, 30, 260692), 'lon', 'del', 'medium'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 7, 18, 15, 333229), 'lon', 'del', 'medium'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 7, 29, 0, 839566), 'lon', 'del', 'medium'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 7, 37, 45, 211979), 'lon', 'del', 'low'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 7, 41, 15, 211376), 'lon', 'del', 'medium'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 7, 48, 16, 26287), 'lon', 'del', 'low'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 7, 55, 17, 248074), 'ny', 'del', 'low'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 7, 57, 2, 55666), 'lon', 'del', 'medium'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 8, 4, 2, 319699), 'lon', 'del', 'low'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 8, 25, 5, 982621), 'ny', 'del', 'medium'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 8, 26, 50, 997280), 'lon', 'del', 'medium'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 8, 39, 7, 14287), 'lon', 'del', 'medium'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 8, 47, 51, 810956), 'lon', 'del', 'medium'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 21, 9, 37, 23, 99922), 'ny', 'del', 'low')]
```

This is how I load it in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ["date", "start", "end", "type"]
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

Now I can get all the rows which have a specific type for example `medium` by doing something like

```
print(df[df.values == 'medium'])
```

Now I want to know for each unique pair of `start` and `end`, what is count of type `medium`? Basically I want something like

```
blr del 1
lon del 9
ny  del 1
```

But I am not sure how can I get that. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with spcify columns for test:

```
s1 = df[df.values == 'medium'].groupby(['start','end']).size()
print (s1)
start  end
blr    del    1
lon    del    9
ny     del    1
dtype: int64
```

Or if want all combinations also with `type`:

```
print(df.groupby(['type','start','end']).size())
type    start  end
low     lon    del    3
        ny     del    2
medium  blr    del    1
        lon    del    9
        ny     del    1
dtype: int64


print (s.loc['medium'])
start  end
blr    del    1
lon    del    9
ny     del    1
dtype: int64


print (s.loc['low'])
start  end
lon    del    3
ny     del    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html):

```
res = df[df['type'].eq('medium')].value_counts()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
start  end  type  
lon    del  medium    9
ny     del  medium    1
blr    del  medium    1
dtype: int64
```

From the documentation:

> Return a Series containing counts of unique rows in the DataFrame.

If you want to remove the type from the output, use droplevel, as suggested by @jezrael:

```
res = df[df['type'].eq('medium')].value_counts().droplevel(level=-1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
start  end
lon    del    9
ny     del    1
blr    del    1
dtype: int64
```

This can also be extended for all types, for example, using:

```
res = df.value_counts(subset=['type', 'start', 'end']).sort_index(level=0)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
type    start  end
low     lon    del    3
        ny     del    2
medium  blr    del    1
        lon    del    9
        ny     del    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `res = df[df['type'].eq('medium')].value_counts().droplevel(-1)`

Comment: Is there an advantage to use `df['type'].eq('medium')` instead of `df['type']=='medium'` which is for me easier to read?

Comment: @MrT In this particular case I don't think theres is any advantage, although I found it more readable with eq, but when you have to combine multiple conditions this saves you the use of parenthesis.

Comment: @SouvikRay Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.where(lambda x:x.type == "medium").dropna().groupby(['start', 'end']).type.agg("count")
```

```
start  end
blr    del    1
lon    del    9
ny     del    1
Name: type, dtype: int64
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.